# ngx-bootstrap typeahead with optionslisttemplate not respecting typeaheadOptionsInScrollableView value

Tags: angular, typeahead, ngx-bootstrap

My recreation of issue - StackBlitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5qqtrs

I am using ngx-bootstrap and the typeahead directive on an input text element.  I need to be able to get the optionsListTemplate to show as a limited height scrollable container.

I want the list container dropdown to scroll with a limited number of items displaying (fixed height) before needing to scroll (by default this is 5 items).

I set the typeaheadOptionsInScrollableView (6) and the typeaheadScrollable (true).  As long as I do not use the optionsListTemplate attribute, then the control displays correctly.

[This shows what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xz6UH.png)

When setting a custom optionsListTemplate, the control does not limit the list of displayed options.

[This shows what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3tVH.png)

While investigating the source code for ngx-bootstrap - typeahead, the  field guiHeight is used internally to set the container height based on the list items height * count from typeaheadOptionsInScrollableView attribute.  This value is returning undefined.

ngx-bootstrap site:

https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/typeahead.

I am using angular 7.x (latest), bootstrap 4.3.1, ngx-bootstrap 3.1.1

Any help appreciated.

-- Ed

Answer (score 1):

In case anybody is still looking for an answer, I "fixed" the issue in my code by wrapping the `optionsListTemplate` inside of a `div` that just has a special CSS-class attached to it. Basically, since no height information is available to the typeaheadComponent, I specify one myself and set that `div` to

```css
.scollable-container {
    max-height: 12rem;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

So it's just a CSS fix but it does the job for me. This makes no use of `typeaheadOptionsInScrollableView`, so be sure to not set that option. Also, I'd recommend setting the input property `typeaheadOptionsLimit` to something larger than what you expect to display inside the scrollable container. By default, it won't render anything beyond 20(?) entries.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation page states that optionsListTemplate has 3 template variables: matches, itemTemplate, query. So I think they never had this in mind

Easiest and fastest fix is to slice the matches array =>

```
<ng-template ngFor let-match let-i="index" [ngForOf]="matches.slice(0,6)">
```

this will only display up to 6 elements

Hope it helps

Comment: I think this would mimic the [typeaheadOptionsLimit] attribute which reduces the source list to only ever provide those 6 items.  What I am looking for is to have the scrollable view display 6 items but still be able to scroll through the remaining match items.

In the attached stackblitz link, the options shows all of the items in one big list instead of scrolling with 6 displaying.

Comment: Oh yes... that is correct... totally miss understood it ... I shall think something else